# 'bond' and 'bonding' tags - is there a reason for keeping both of them?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Presently, there are two bond-tags: 'bond' and 'bonding'. Both seem to be pretty much equivalent to me. The 'bond' tag has a description and is used more frequently while the 'bonding' tag lacks a description. I suggest that both tags should be merged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many of the questions that had the tag [bonding](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bonding) already had the tag [bond](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bond), so I went ahead and merged the tags into [bond](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bond) and made [bonding](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bonding) a synonym.

Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed it while answering a question.